# Listen to click on ONLY on the map of Google Maps embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Map with markers on it. When the user clicks on a marker, a sidebar slides out by adding a class to the sidebar element.

Now, I want to hide the sidebar when the user clicks somewhere on the map.

I added an click event listener on the map, but it also gets triggered when the user clicks on the marker. So the sidebar is shown and hidden immediately.

Marker event listener:
`maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerClicked);`

Map event listener:
`maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function() {`

How can I detect a click ONLY the map?

**---EDIT---**

Allright, some code on request:

For every marker I add to the map I activate a click event listener like this:
`google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', markerClicked);`

The `markerClicked` function contains the following code which opens a sidebar:

```
var markerClicked = function() {
    $('.sidebar--slide-in').addClass('sidebar--slide-in-active');
};
```

Also when the map is created I activate a click event listener for the map, like this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, "click", function() {

});
```

The marker click listener works like a charm. When a marker is clicked, it returns the clicked marker. When the map is clicked nothing happens.

The map click event listener however returns an object when the map is clicked, but also when a marker is clicked.

When the map is clicked(not when a marker is clicked!) I want to close the sidebar. How do I do this?

**---EDIT 2---**

I failed to mention I use custom markers. I thought this didn't affect the problem in any way. It appears it does. I copied the codepen from @Dekel and added my custom marker in it.

http://codepen.io/nieknijland/pen/QKyaxw

Now when you click the marker both alerts are triggered. I just want te marker alert te be triggered, not the map click event.

Comment: Add some code that demonstrates the problem, otherwise the question most likely will be closed. You are not new to SO, you should already know that!

Comment: What kind of code do you want? I just want to know if it is possible to listen to a click even listener only when the map is clicked. Not when a marker, or any other element in the Google Maps embed is clicked.

I understand that I have to add code normally, but not in this case I think :)

Comment: Well, I can tell you "yes, it's possible..." but it will be much better if you show a code that doesn't work and someone will show you what the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: I hope my edit adds enough information? Or do you want a Fiddle showing it?

Comment: You shouldn't use `addDomListener` to handle your map click events, you should use `addListener`, just like you do with the markers.  The `map` is a Google object, not a DOM element.

Comment: @NiekNijland, did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I did not work on this project for the past few days. I will try it today or tomorrow, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpoqPK

This is the code (doesn't work in snippet)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Simple markers</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
            height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            function initMap() {
                var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    zoom: 4,
                    center: myLatLng
                });

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'Hello World!'
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    alert('Marker clicked')
                });

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(map, "click", function() {
                    alert('Map clicked')
                });
            }
        </script>
        <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Make sure to add the event listener on the map **after** the map is initialized

## Update

If you use a custom marker and you want to prevent the `click` event on the map when you click on the marker you can add the `stopPropagation` function of the event when clicked on that marker:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    google.maps.event.trigger(self, 'click', event);
});
```

Here is an updated codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGAQdW

Comment: I tried your solution and found out it works with standard Google Maps markers. I didn't mention I use custom markers, because I thought it wouldn't matter. However when I use custom markers and I click a marker, both alert windows are triggered. I will copy your codepen and recreate the problem, then I will edit my question again!

Comment: I just added a copy of your codepen and added my custom markers in it.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that -.- Thanks for your help!

Comment: @NiekNijland, which browser?

Comment: Safari for iOS. I found a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997804/stopeventpropagation-not-working-on-mobile-safari-or-chrome-dev-tools-emulation